# How to prevent and validate between 4 date period, 2 start date and 2 end date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 to validate 4 date time for check betweeon 2 period **(each user has their own period)**.

When first period saved with start and end date, then next input only input after the end date can be saved

For example :

First period that has been saved : **Feb/01/2019 - May/30/2019**
then for the next input Period (new start and end date) **only after May/30/2019.**
When this user save the next period like Mar/04/2019 - Jun/20/2019 is rejected, as well as with Mar/01/2019 - Apr/20/2019 is rejected.

And when second period has been saved : **Jun/05/2019 - Aug/05/2019**
then for the next input Period (new start and end date) **only after Aug/05/2019.**
and so on.

Likewise with other users who have their respective periods.

Thanks.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about Laravel for now, and focus on the SQL.

Comment: Thanks. but How does it work? is it in migration?

Comment: I understand no part of that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your `User` has a `start` and `end` property, and they're submitting a form with a new `start` and `end` value.

You need to write a rule that validates that the input `start` is after the user's `end` which you can do using the [after rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-after) by passing it the user's `end`, e.g:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'start' => 'required|after:' . Auth::user()->end,
]);
```

If you are accepting multiple dates within the same form submission you can pass the name of the field that contains the date to compare against instead of passing a date, that's included in the documentation. Along with `after` there is also a `before` rule which works in the same way.

Comment: Nice, it works!
but in my case, start and end date located in different model, so like this.
$find_endDate = Submission::find(auth()->user()->lastSubmissionID);
                    $validatedData = $request->validate([
                        'startDate' => 'required|before:endDate|after:'.$find_endDate->ends,
                        'endDate' => 'required',
                    ]);
Thanks, you save my day. :)